# "Server not found" error until refresh

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system

On one of my web servers I've had visitors say that the first time they try to visit a website on that server their browser reports a "Server not found" error but when they hit refresh it loads properly.

Is it possible that this is a server configuration or perhaps a DNS issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Server not Found" is most likely the DNS. Is it just one website or every website on that server? 
Even better, is the DNS for those websites hosted on that server as well? You may check to see if the DNS server is occasionally having problems.